# Generate DbContext and Models on runtime using connection string Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is there any way, where I can generate the DbContext at runtime only the use of connection string?

We can generate models and DbContext of an existing database on entity framework core using Scaffold, which have to run from Package Manager Console or Power Shell. Based on this the idea has come in my mind, where is it possible to execute the Scaffold command from a console application in runtime, where application will provide the dynamic connection string.

Any alternate or good suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Will you persist on  one connection or what like to change it when requires?

Comment: Want to change frequently.

Comment: if what you are asking is to pass different connection strings dynamically on the same dbcontext at runtime yes it is possible

Comment: No, you are wrong, I noticed scaffold and existing database, which means database first. I will change the connection string manually.

Comment: how would you code against a dbcontext that is generated at runtime?

Comment: @Fran using reflation we can get the dbcontext and all of it's models

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible. [Roslyn & EF Core: runtime DbContext constructing](https://medium.com/@zaikinsr/roslyn-ef-core-runtime-dbcontext-constructing-285a9d67bc87)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Diagnostics.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace RuntimeEfCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = args.Length > 0
                ? args[0]
                : throw new Exception("Pass connection string as a first parameter");

            var scaffolder = CreateMssqlScaffolder();

            var dbOpts = new DatabaseModelFactoryOptions();
            var modelOpts = new ModelReverseEngineerOptions();
            var codeGenOpts = new ModelCodeGenerationOptions()
            {
                RootNamespace = "TypedDataContext",
                ContextName = "DataContext",
                ContextNamespace = "TypedDataContext.Context",
                ModelNamespace = "TypedDataContext.Models",
                SuppressConnectionStringWarning = true
            };

            var scaffoldedModelSources = scaffolder.ScaffoldModel(connectionString, dbOpts, modelOpts, codeGenOpts);
            var sourceFiles = new List<string> { scaffoldedModelSources.ContextFile.Code };
            sourceFiles.AddRange(scaffoldedModelSources.AdditionalFiles.Select(f => f.Code));

            using var peStream = new MemoryStream();

            var enableLazyLoading = false;
            var result = GenerateCode(sourceFiles, enableLazyLoading).Emit(peStream);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                var failures = result.Diagnostics
                    .Where(diagnostic => diagnostic.IsWarningAsError || 
                                        diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                var error = failures.FirstOrDefault();
                throw new Exception($"{error?.Id}: {error?.GetMessage()}");
            }

            var assemblyLoadContext = new AssemblyLoadContext("DbContext", isCollectible: !enableLazyLoading);

            peStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var assembly = assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(peStream);

            var type = assembly.GetType("TypedDataContext.Context.DataContext");
            _ = type ?? throw new Exception("DataContext type not found");

            var constr = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            _ = constr ?? throw new Exception("DataContext ctor not found");

            DbContext dynamicContext = (DbContext)constr.Invoke(null);
            var entityTypes = dynamicContext.Model.GetEntityTypes();

            Console.WriteLine($"Context contains {entityTypes.Count()} types");

            foreach (var entityType in dynamicContext.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                var items = (IQueryable<object>)dynamicContext.Query(entityType.Name);

                Console.WriteLine($"Entity type: {entityType.ClrType.Name} contains {items.Count()} items");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

            if (!enableLazyLoading)
            {
                assemblyLoadContext.Unload();
            }
        }

        static IReverseEngineerScaffolder CreateMssqlScaffolder() =>
            new ServiceCollection()
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddLogging()
            .AddEntityFrameworkDesignTimeServices()
            .AddSingleton<LoggingDefinitions, SqlServerLoggingDefinitions>()
            .AddSingleton<IRelationalTypeMappingSource, SqlServerTypeMappingSource>()
            .AddSingleton<IAnnotationCodeGenerator, AnnotationCodeGenerator>()
            .AddSingleton<IDatabaseModelFactory, SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory>()
            .AddSingleton<IProviderConfigurationCodeGenerator, SqlServerCodeGenerator>()
            .AddSingleton<IScaffoldingModelFactory, RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory>()
            .AddSingleton<IPluralizer, Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Pluralizer>()
            .BuildServiceProvider()
            .GetRequiredService<IReverseEngineerScaffolder>();


        static List<MetadataReference> CompilationReferences(bool enableLazyLoading)
        {
            var refs = new List<MetadataReference>();
            var referencedAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
            refs.AddRange(referencedAssemblies.Select(a => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load(a).Location)));

            refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
            refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0").Location));
            refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Data.Common.DbConnection).Assembly.Location));
            refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression).Assembly.Location));

            if (enableLazyLoading)
            {
                refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ProxiesExtensions).Assembly.Location));
            }

            return refs;
        }

        private static CSharpCompilation GenerateCode(List<string> sourceFiles, bool enableLazyLoading)
        {
            var options = CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithLanguageVersion(LanguageVersion.CSharp8);

            var parsedSyntaxTrees = sourceFiles.Select(f => SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(f, options));

            return CSharpCompilation.Create($"DataContext.dll",
                parsedSyntaxTrees,
                references: CompilationReferences(enableLazyLoading),
                options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
                    optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Release,
                    assemblyIdentityComparer: DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default));
        }
    }

    public static class DynamicContextExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable Query(this DbContext context, string entityName) =>
            context.Query(context.Model.FindEntityType(entityName).ClrType);

        static readonly MethodInfo SetMethod =
            typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set), 1, Array.Empty<Type>()) ??
            throw new Exception($"Type not found: DbContext.Set");

        public static IQueryable Query(this DbContext context, Type entityType) =>
            (IQueryable)SetMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType)?.Invoke(context, null) ??
            throw new Exception($"Type not found: {entityType.FullName}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With EF 5, my solution was to run an EF CLI command attached to the project's pre-build event.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == TEST1 (

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold name=dbConnStringName Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --startup-project ../C2C-PublicApi/C2C.PublicApi.Api.csproj -p ./C2C.PublicApi.Data.csproj -o Entities -n C2C.PublicApi.Data.Entities --context-dir ./DataContexts --context-namespace C2C.PublicApi.Data.DataContexts -c C2CApiDbContext -t [dbo].[tbl_AnaestheticType] -t [dbo].[tbl_Appointment] -t [dbo].[tbl_AppointmentCancellationReason] -t [dbo].[tbl_AppointmentCancellationSource] -t [dbo].[tbl_AppointmentConsultType] -t [dbo].[tbl_AppointmentType] -t [dbo].[tbl_BillingAccountType] --no-pluralize --no-onconfiguring **--no-build** --force

)
```

Most likely, you will run it before the build event of your data library. Also, it is important to include the **--no-build** option presuming your project is updated and does not need recompiling.